# Structs in shared memory in C using mmap

Tags: c, shared-memory, mmap

I've read earlier questions and answers to my question, however the majority appear to be using shmget rather than mmap.

I was using mmap for shared memory and it was all working fine, until I changed from using static variables to structs. Currently, I'm getting the following errors:

```
server.c: In function ‘interfaceComms’:
server.c:129:18: error: ‘interfaceConnection’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  n = write(sock, interfaceConnection->processingResults, 47);
                  ^
server.c:129:18: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
server.c:139:12: error: ‘imageDetails’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  if(strcmp(imageDetails->prevImage, "") != 0) {
            ^
server.c: In function ‘robotComms’:
server.c:162:2: error: ‘imageDetails’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  imageDetails->prevImage = imageDetails->currImage;
  ^
server.c:213:9: error: ‘interfaceConnection’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  strcpy(interfaceConnection->processingResults, msg);
```

I understand the error, however I'm not sure how to resolve it using structs as this is the way I thought shared memory was done. I'm forking, so the structs are being used in child processes.

My code:

```
typedef struct Images {
    char prevImage;
    char currImage;
} image;

typedef struct Robot {
    char coordinates;
} robot;

typedef struct Interface {
    char processingResults;
} interface;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen, memid;
char buffer[256];
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
int n, pid;
interface *interfaceConnection;
image *imageDetails;

// First call to socket() function
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if (sockfd < 0){
    perror("Error opening socket");
    exit(1);
}

// Initialise socket structure
bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
portno = 5001;

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

//Bind the socket
if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
    perror("Error binding socket");
    exit(1);
}

//Listen for client connections
listen(sockfd,5);
clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

//Share memory before forking
interfaceConnection = mmap(NULL, sizeof(interface), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
                MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

imageDetails = mmap(NULL, sizeof(image), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
            MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

The function 'interfaceComms' and 'robotComms' are called later on after the fork has happened. But I'm guessing my issue is up there somewhere.

As requested, the intefaceComms and robotComms functions:

```
void checkMessage(int sock){
int n;
char message[256];
n = read(sock, message, 255);
int response;

if(n < 0){
    perror("Error reading the socket");
    exit(1);
}

//see if the message is from the robot or from the interface
if(strstr(message,"robot") != NULL) {
    //The robot wants the co-ordinates of the component
    robotComms(sock);
} else {
    //Someone has accessed the main page
    interfaceComms(sock);
}
}

void interfaceComms(int sock) {
int n;

n = write(sock, interfaceConnection->processingResults, 47);

if (n < 0){
    perror("Error writing to the socket");
    exit(1);
} else {
    printf("Results sent to interface\n");
}
}

void robotComms(int sock) {
int n;
srand ( time(NULL) ); //reset rand
//printf("Here is the message: %s\n", message);
printf("Getting image...\n");

//Change currImage to prevImage
imageDetails->prevImage = imageDetails->currImage;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I'm guessing my issue is up there somewhere". Please don't guess (you are here precisely because you don't know where the error is). Just show us all the info. In particular it would be logical to show at least the lines of code where those compile errors are coming from. That is, show at least the `interfaceComms` function at the minimum. But preferrably provide a [minimal complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Updated. There are parts of my code that I can't show, however I think the added code should cover what you asked for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that interfaceConnection is a local variable in your main function.

```
interface *interfaceConnection;
```

I am assuming you want this at the global scope.  Its hard to tell without seeing the other code.

Comment: Yes.  And of course this has nothing specifically to do with shared memory.

Comment: Thank you! Knew it'd be something so painfully obvious!!

Comment: @mfisher91 I think either you're not a C developer (which is fine! everyone that is wasn't at first), or you posted this problem way too early... unresolved identifiers (when they're your identifiers in the first place) should not generally require help in resolving.

Comment: The latter :(. I was stressed, it is late, I probably should stop working!